# Insert image from VBA to EXCEL in a special case (=INCORPORER("Forms.Image.1";"")

Tags: vba, excel

I insert an image from VBA to Excel in Cell F31.

```
With Worksheets("CheckListIndustrialisation").Pictures.Insert(image) 
    '.Top = [F31].Top
    '.Left = [F31].Left
    '.Width = [F31].Width
    '.Height = [F31].Height
```

But what I would like to do is to insert my image in the same sheet of excel but in one special case for image and not F31. The code inside the special case of image is:

```
=INCORPORER("Forms.Image.1";"")
```

I don't find how to change my code.

Comment: It is not clear to me, at least, what you are actually asking.  Perhaps you can add some more description or examples to make your question more clear.

Comment: @MichaelOryl He's trying to insert `OleObject` of Image control type. `INCORPORER` is French for `EMBED` I think which is what we usually see on English versions of XL.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is add an `OleObject` in the worksheet.
Try below:

```
'First add the OleOject
Dim img As OLEObject, sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("CheckListIndustrialisation")
Set img = sh.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=147, Top:=42, Width:=85.5, Height:=37.5)

'Second add image to your OleObject
Dim iobj As MSForms.Image
Set iobj = img.Object
iobj.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\User.Name\Pictures\SamplePicture.gif")
```

I declared and set the object types so you'll know what type of object you're working on.
In VBA, certain type of objects belong to certain collection of objects.
You'll need to check the specific type of object you want so work on so you can view the available properties and method for it and thus execute the correct code. HTH.